# cannot import <gamekit/gamekit.h>?

Tags: xcode4, import, gamekit

I have added the `gamekit` framework to my project in `XCode 4`, but when i try to type

```
#import <gamekit/gamekit.h>
```

it does not recognize it. I have tried to remove and re-add the `gamekit` framework, but it has not helped. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do restart your system or MAC and then check for it and add framework in project settings "Link Framework and Liabraries". It will help you. Mine is working properly for

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
```